# My Flash Dirve is write protected

Tags: installation, usb, flash, drive, usb-drive

My Flash Drive is write protected. How can I remove the write protected? My Flash Drive brand is SanDisk.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/502488/usb-turn-write-protection-off-forced/559071#559071

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is faulty:

From the [SanDisk Forum](http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/All-SanDisk-USB-Flash-Drives/SanDisk-Cruzer-Blade-16GB-write-protected-error/td-p/253484/page/7):

> Re: SanDisk Cruzer Blade 16GB write protected error
>   ‎> 05-17-2012 10:55 AM
>
> Dear All who are suffering from write protection error,
>
> The customer service answered to me and they know about the issue, so here it is to clarify the situation to everyone:
>
> "I understand that you are getting write protection error while accessing your Cruzer flash drive. The flash drive has detected a potential fault and has become write protected to prevent data loss. There is no method to fix this. You will need to backup your data and replace the flash drive.
>   Our team of developers is in combination with the OS developers looking into a solution to resolve this issue.
>   Please note that only a minor percentage of users are experiencing the write protection issue and these are the customers posting on the internet to find a solution."
>   So wait, or change back your drive if it's under warranty...